# Color area beneath sympy function plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, sympy

I have a sympy function, I want to plot it and color the area beneath the curve, how can I do it?

**Code**

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.symbols('x')
f = sy.sin(x)

sy.plot(f, (x, 0, sy.pi))
```

**Plot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.fill_between` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)) but you need to convert your `sympy` function in a `numpy` array with `sy.lambdify` ([documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)) before, because `plt.fill_between` takes in arrays.
Check this code as a reference:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sy.symbols('x')
f = sy.sin(x)

x_array = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
f_array = sy.lambdify(x, f)(x_array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x_array, f_array, color = 'red')
ax.fill_between(x_array, f_array, facecolor = 'red', alpha = 0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would have preferred to avoid converting the sympy analytic functions to arrays, but it is still fine

Answer (score 2):

i have created the same output without using matplotlib directly(sympy already uses sympy)

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = sy.symbols('x')
f = sy.sin(x)
x_array = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
f_array = sy.lambdify(x, f)(x_array)
plot(f, (x, 0, sy.pi), fill={'x': x_array,'y1':f_array,'color':'green'})
```

i got the output
[image]