# ERROR :" fill_between() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y1' " while using fill_between in area filled line plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I used agg to find mean and min values grouped by age. Then tried to plot area filled line graph.

```
grpby = df6.groupby('age')
mean_values = grpby.agg({'hoursperweek':np.mean})
min_values = grpby.agg({'hoursperweek':np.min})


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(mean_values,label = 'mean')
plt.plot(min_values,label = 'min',linestyle = '--')
plt.fill_between(mean_values,alpha = 0.25)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Mean and min')
plt.xlabel('ages')
plt.ylabel('hrs per week')
plt.show()
```

My mean values output :

```
     hoursperweek
age              
31      42.877252
32      42.878019
33      42.965714
34      42.937923
35      43.908676
36      43.257238
37      43.706294
...
...
```

I'm getting the following error

```
    plt.fill_between(mean_values,alpha = 0.25)
TypeError: fill_between() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y1'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `plt.fill_between()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) reports, this function need **at least** two parameters:

> **xarray** (length N)
> The x coordinates of the nodes defining the curves.
>
> **y1array** (length N) or scalar
> The y coordinates of the nodes defining the first curve.

The area you want to fill is defined by two functions `f1` and `f2`, you need to pass to  `plt.fill_between()`:

1. the array of the x coordinates of the points of `f1`
2. the array of the y coordinates of the points of `f1`
3. (optionally) the array of the y coordinates of the points of `f2`. If you do not specify `f2`, `plt.fill_between()` will automatically use the x axis in its place.

In your code,

> `plt.fill_between(mean_values,alpha = 0.25)`

you are specifying `mean_values` only, which matplotlib interprets how `xarray`, so it requires you for `y1`, as the error reports.
Check these answers as a reference:

- [Color area beneath sympy function plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62859300/9214357)
- [Python Seaborn Chart - Shadow Area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654700/9214357)

Comment: Thanks! I divided the dataframe into two lists ( x and y axis) and tried, it worked!